# Temporal Logic Tautology

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I have the following question:

[image: question]

```
if it is necessary that p -> p = tautology?
```

I think it's not, and I am showing my example for the contradiction, below:

[image: example]

And I'll explain:

For every "universe" which is reachable for S1, p is true (hence םp).

For a universe that isn't reachable for S1, p is false (and therefore, this is not a tautology).

But are my observations correct?

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is not correct.   $\Box p \to p$ does *not* say "if $p$ is true in all accessible worlds it is true in all worlds (even the inaccessible ones)"

It just says "if $p$ is true in all worlds accessible from *this one*, then it is true in *this world*;" for an given world of interest.  Which is true *if and only* the world of interest is accessible to itself.

---

Still the point remains that necessity and possibility are relative concepts.

By definition, a predicate is necessarily true *if and only if* the predicate is true in all *accessible* worlds.   This is *always* evaluated relative to some world of interest.  When the world is omitted, we're usually interested in the "actual world" by default.

So $w \vDash \Box p\to p \;$ says, if predicate $p$ is true in all worlds accessible to world $w$ then $p$ is true in world $w$.

However, this is not a tautology; it is the **Axiom of Reflexivity**.   It *only* holds in models where the accessibility relation is reflexive.   (Ie: When every world in the frame can access itself.)

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was great and helped me a lot.